# Elegant way to get unique mask in tensorflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Currently on `tensorflow 1.15`.

I have a batch of sequences, I want to have a boolean mask that would indicate the first unique items within one sequence as `True`. So for example:

```
sequences = tf.Tensor(
    [
        ["1", "2", "3", "2"],
        ["4", "2", "5", "6"],
        ["7", "7", "4", "7"],
    ],
)
```

I would get:

```
[
    [True, True, True, False],
    [True, True, True, True],
    [True, False, True, False],
],
```

Is there an elegant way to do it? `tf.unique` seems to be limited to 1-D tensors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a custom mask_row function. this function selects the first unique elements in the row and creates a mask. this function is iterated on all the rows with map_fn

```
sequences = tf.constant([
        ["1", "2", "3", "2"],
        ["4", "2", "5", "6"],
        ["7", "7", "4", "7"]])


def mask_row(row):
    mask = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.math.equal(tf.range(row.shape[-1]), 
                                        tf.cast(tf.math.reduce_min(tf.where(tf.math.equal(row, x))), tf.int32)), 
                     row, dtype=tf.bool)
    return tf.math.reduce_any(mask, axis=0)


tf.map_fn(mask_row, sequences, dtype=tf.bool)
```

result

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 4), dtype=bool, numpy=
array([[ True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, False]])>
```

Comment: if you consider the answer valuable, don't forget to accept it as answer ;-)

Comment: Of course, just giving a little room for potential other answers! Yours definitely does the trick, though I am concerned about the potential performance hit (will have to check the impact, `map_fn` always makes me wary.